# Angular library - Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular12

I have the simples example:

1. I create Angular library inside workspace from official documentation:

```
ng new workspace-test --create-application=false
cd workspace-test
ng generate library lib-test
```

2. Then I build library and I create npm link for it from ./dist/lib-test directory:

```
ng build lib-test
npm link
```

3. Then I create simplest angular application:

```
ng new app-test
```

4. Now I link my application to the library:

```
npm link lib-test
```

5. When I try to use library inside my app, I get exception

```
 Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../workspace-test/dist/lib-test/lib/lib-test.component' in 'C:\dev\app-test\src\app'
```

6. My usage of the library in the app:

```
import { LibTestModule } from '../../../workspace-test/dest/lib-test'


...


imports: [
   LibTestModule ,
```

I don't have idea what is going on, how to make it work? It basic example.

Comment: You npm linked it, but you seem to import it from a local path? Just import from ‘lib-test’?

Comment: It worked! But now when I open app in the browser I get an errror in the console: Error: inject() must be called from an injection context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use local library in another local project then your library build should be inside project's node_modules folder

solution
change the library build destination to the project's node_modules

- assume you have the following folders

  [image]
- go to `my-lib>projects>my-lib>ng-package.json` file
- change dest to `"../../../my-project/node_modules/my-lib"`
- build your library

Comment: I am doing everything same as @Ellbar however, I am publishing the npm package to Azure DevOps Artifacts.

When I try and install it from package.json of the new project, I get "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve Module" error.

What m I doing wrong?

Comment: @Immortal did you ever resolve that issue? I am experiencing the exact same thing with Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

You can install your missing module in node_module folder after building it.

Build your lib:
`cd my-lib`
`ng build`

 Go to your workspace root:
`cd my-workspace`

Then install via npm:
`npm i ./dist/my-lib`